# How to query and update value in firebase realtime database based on a specific condition?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
In this database, timeout is null right now so it isn't showing. When I click a particular button I want timeout to update in the particular database. But in the future this db will be populated by tons of device so I want to sort through the database and look for device with a particular name and update timeout for only a particular device where timeout is null.

I am not able to figure how to sort through the database with unique keys and update where timeout is null for a specific devicename. I thought I would do something like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("userName").equalTo("Nick123");
query.addValueEventListener(/\* ... \*/);
```

And then nest something similar for timeout inside this, but how would get the corresponding key of the timeout filed that was null. Even if i save the key while pushing it it just doesn't make sense. Can anyone please help me through this?

Comment: Show us the exact query that you're using, that doesn't provide the results you're expecting.

Comment: I have tried many snippets of code inspired by the one above, and now out of frustration have wiped the slate clean, and I want to start from scratch. Since I don't have any sort of VCS in my project enabled right now, I woudn't be able to show you what I had tried.

Comment: "In this database, timeout is null right now so it isn't showing." There is no `timeout` in the database screenshot you shared. It's not that it's `null` and hidden, but it simply doesn't exist. --- In case you want to query on nodes without a `timeout`, that isn't possible since Firebase only indexes (and thus can only filter on) properties that *do* exist in the data.

Comment: Ahh I understand, but how do I query the database twice? Like I first want to go through the database by devicename and then by timeout so that I can find the uid under which timeout is empty and update that